# Google analytics views per page_url instead of views per title

Tags: google-analytics

I have two projects in google analytics.

- First project was created in September 2020. This one shows views per page url. Super useful.
- Second project was created in December 2020. This one only shows views per page title. I have same page title on all pages hence this doesn't help.

Is there any setting that I missed or has google changed its analytics.

Thanks

Comment: They are the same or different code (one UA-XXXX-XX and the other G-XXXXX)?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new property, Google now creates a *Google Analytics 4* property. This allows you to combine user data from mobile apps with data from your website. By creating a *Universal Analytics* property everything should be as how it was before.

1. Delete your current property.
2. Create a new property and click *Show advanced options* at step 1 (Property setup).
3. Enable create a Universal Analytics property.
4. Enter your website URL and click *Create a Universal Analytics property only*.

The Google Analytics environments should now match, thus showing views per page URL.